# limit of log(n) over floor(log(n))

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Hi I was comparing two functions and I wanter to check if they showed the same ~ behaviour. So I took the the limit, I unfortunatly wasn't able to calculate it myself so I used wolfram alpha instead yielding :

[image]

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812572/42969

Comment: You can define $x=\log(n)$ in the linked duplicate.